# Cookie isn't accessible from sibling and parent path

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to set from this route localhost:3000/cart/add-to-cart
But the cookie isn't sent for any other sibling or parent paths on the domain.

I'm using Express and this is my code where I set the cookie (pretty simple)

```
  if (!req.cookies.uniqueId) {
    uniqueId = uuidv4();
    res.cookie("uniqueId", uniqueId, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 86400000,
      sameSite : "none",
      secure : true
    });
  } else {
    uniqueId = req.cookies.uniqueId;
  }
```

But when I try to access the cookie, as I mentioned, I can't.

I'm trying to access it from localhost:3000/ or localhost:3000/cart
I've tried a lot of things, setting path : "/" and so on.

It works on Postman but not on Firefox by the way.

Comment: Secure cookies are set only over https, not over http. Does your server use https?

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing issues with the cookie not being sent for sibling or parent paths on the domain, there are a few potential reasons and solutions you can try.

SameSite attribute:
The sameSite attribute controls when cookies should be sent with cross-site requests. In your code, you have set it to "none," which means the cookie should be sent with both cross-site and same-site requests. However, for the sameSite attribute to work with the "none" value, the secure attribute must also be set to true.
Since you mentioned it works on Postman but not on Firefox, it's worth noting that starting in Firefox 86, the browser enforces the Secure attribute for cookies with sameSite=none. Therefore, to ensure compatibility with Firefox, make sure you are using HTTPS (secure connection) during development, not HTTP.

Path attribute:
The path attribute defines the scope of the cookie and restricts which paths on your domain can access the cookie. By default, the path is set to the current path. Since you want the cookie to be accessible from multiple paths, you should set the path attribute to '/' to make it available to all paths on the domain.
Here's an updated version of your code with the path attribute set explicitly to '/':

```js
if (!req.cookies.uniqueId) {
  uniqueId = uuidv4();
  res.cookie("uniqueId", uniqueId, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 86400000,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
    path: "/"
  });
} else {
  uniqueId = req.cookies.uniqueId;
}
```

By setting the path attribute to '/', the cookie should be accessible from both localhost:3000/ and localhost:3000/cart.

Remember to ensure you have a secure connection (HTTPS) during development to test the cookies in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to set a https server
I understand better now, thought my code was wrong

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution

The cookie wasn't available on the cart page because I've fetched using

https://localhost:8080/cart

instead of

https://127.0.0.1:8080/cart